# Deserialize XML with XmlSerializer where parent and child have the same tag

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having difficulty parsing an XML string where the parent and child nodes have the same tag name. Obviously, I could replace the open/close tags with empty strings and parse with the code below, but that's not elegant.

I've searched and see that there are answers for how to do this with XDocument, but I specifically would like to do this with XmlSerializer (if possible).

Below is a minimal, reproducable example.

Example XML:

```
<AddJob>
    <AddJob RequestStatus="OK" RequestMessage="Job successfuly added [testPrintServer.tif, PES_Carpet_16C_76.2 x 50.8 dpi_170517_Normal]" UUID="74ad5971-7baf-49ce-b85b-ee08188d5721" />
</AddJob>
```

Parsing code:

```
public class XmlHelper
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        T result;
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Data model:

```
[XmlRoot("AddJob")]
public class AddJob
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RequestStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RequestMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("UUID")]
    public string RipJobId { get; set; }
}
```

Calling code:

```
var addedJobResponse = XmlHelper.Deserialize<AddJob>(exampleXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model doesn't match your xml structure.

Please use something like that:

```
[XmlRoot("AddJob")]
public class AddJob
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddJob")]
    public List<NestedAddJob> AddJobs { get; set; }
}

public class NestedAddJob
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RequestStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string RequestMessage { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("UUID")]
    public string RipJobId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While there will only be at most one AddJob (for the moment), your solution is future proof in case the software vendor ever decides to return more than one AddJob. Kudos

Answer (score 1):

The nested AddJob elements look like an array and you cannot have an array at the root.  So add a Root class like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string xml = "<AddJob>" +
              "<AddJob RequestStatus=\"OK\" RequestMessage=\"Job successfuly added [testPrintServer.tif, PES_Carpet_16C_76.2 x 50.8 dpi_170517_Normal]\" UUID=\"74ad5971-7baf-49ce-b85b-ee08188d5721\" />" +
              "</AddJob>";
           Root job = XmlHelper.Deserialize<Root>(xml);

        }

    }
    public class XmlHelper
    {

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            T result;
            using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("AddJob")]
    public class Root
    {
        public AddJob AddJob { get; set; }
    }
    public class AddJob
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string RequestStatus { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string RequestMessage { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("UUID")]
        public string RipJobId { get; set; }
    }



}
```